# HTML set footer image on each print page

Tags: html, css

I am able to set text on every print page but if I have to set image in place of text, what necessary changes do I have to make?  Here's the code I have used so far:

```
<div class="divFooter">UNCLASSIFIED</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media screen {
        div.divFooter {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    @media print {
        div.divFooter {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@media print {
    div.divFooter {
        position: fixed;
        background: url(http://path/to/image.png);
        height: 100px; /* put the image height here */
        width: 100px; /* put the image width here */
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Of course, you can also do something like this instead without using *any* extra CSS:

```
<div class="divFooter"><img src="..." /></div>
```

There are lots of options, it really depends on what exactly you want to accomplish.

Comment: thanx jon..but on "footer image logo". i have to put page no on each and every page..something like 1/5 , 2/5...etc.. where 5 is total no of page..how to do this?

Comment: note that adding a background image is silly: browsers disable background image by default (users need to turn the background img manually in their browser's preferences). So you probably want to use the second solution with the <img src="..." /> if you want to display an image inside the "print-only-repeating" footer

Comment: does this work at all on chrome? this only appears on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following in your CSS and set the `width` and `height` according to your requirement, you may also set padding:

```
.divFooter {
    background:url(imagepath);
    float: left or center; // according to ur requirement
    width: ... ;
    height: ....;
}
```